# Add code to onclick attribute of links

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, google-analytics

I'd like to add a JavaScript code inside the `onclick` attribute of each link of a list. The code is used for google analytics event tracking.

This is the list:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <a href="">Alberto Guardiani</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Antica Bottega</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Ash</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Ballin</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

And this is what it should be like after the jquery appends the onclick code:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <a href="" onclick="_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2, 'Designer', 'text1', 3]);">text1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="" onclick="_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2, 'Designer', 'text2', 3]);">text2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="" onclick="_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2, 'Designer', 'text3', 3]);">text3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="" onclick="_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2, 'Designer', 'text4', 3]);">text4</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

I have no idea if that's even possible with jQuery `append` or what else should I do with this issue. Could you suggest some kind of solution?

Comment: You're going to struggle to do it with jQuery without some form of id/class on those links. Personally I'd be doing this server side, I'm guessing those values come from a database anyway.

Comment: @Dunhamzzz I wouldn't do it server-side because the `onclick` attribute shouldn't be used anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("ol li a").click(function() {
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2, 'Designer', $(this).html(), 3]);
});
```

**Edit:**

If it doesn't work you may have forgot to check if the document is completely loaded.

In this case you should wrap the code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    /* jQuery code */
});
```

Comment: That seems a good way to do it. In order to test if it's actually working I replaced _gaq.push() with alert() but there are no alerts onclick. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Also wanna point out though that `_setCustomVar` just sets a custom variable, it doesn't actually trigger a tracking request to GA.  You need to also call something like `_trackEvent`

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery:

```
$('ol li a').click(function() {
    _gaq.push(); // your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand your question, you can do this using the `click` handler.

**Html**

```
<li>
    <a class="someClassName" href="">Alberto Guardiani</a>
</li>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".someClassName").click(function() {
     _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2, 'Designer', 'text1', 3]);
});
```